# Illegal pattern character 'N' when importing arff file to ARFF Viewer

Tags: csv, attributes, weka, import-from-excel, arff

I get an error while importing arff data set into Weka ARFF viewer as: [Illegal Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bex9j.png)

And when i try to import the csv file into Weka Explorer, all the atrributes seems as one attribute: [all_is_one_attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SODz2.png)

I read all the questions about these, also tried the suggested solutions but i didnt solve the import problem yet.

Comment: Could you upload a sample of your data?  I am guessing your ARFF is not in the correct format.  You can view the actual file in a text editor and it may give you some clues.  http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Answer (score 0):

From the image it seems that you use `;` as a delimiter. Try to replace it with `,`